# A reference for the Tannaka-Krein theorem

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, locally-compact-groups, quantum-groups

I am looking for a reference for the Tannaka-Krein theorem on compact groups. By the Tannaka-Krein theorem which is also called (classic) Tannaka duality (because of the quantum theory), I mean the theory which is to reconstruct a compact (Lie) group from its representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself. It is in

Hewitt, Edwin; Ross, Kenneth A. *Abstract harmonic analysis. Vol. II: Structure and analysis for compact groups. Analysis on locally compact Abelian groups.*  Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, Band 152 Springer-Verlag, New York-Berlin 1970 ix+771 pp.

Section 30. It is written with all the details and preliminaries that one may need.